# InlineAutoData Data For Specific Parameter Argument

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit.net, autofixture

Suppose I have the following parameterized test,

```
[Theory]
[InlineAutoData(typeof(IFoo), null)
public void FooBar(IFoo foo, IBar bar)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

The above will throw an exception about converting `RuntimeType` to `IFoo`.

My question, is how do I tell AutoFixture to generate a member for the first parameter, and use null for the second in this scenario (or is it possible)?

As far as I can tell `InlineAutoData` has the limitation that you have to specify data in-order and any unspecified data gets auto-generated, but that's not exactly ideal and I'm hoping I'm wrong?

Comment: The easiest solution is to change the order of parameters.

Comment: I take it there is no in-place fix then?  Unfortunately that's not a really desirable solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to this as well, but I think this will explain why: "Uses the InlineData values for the the first method arguments, and then uses AutoData for the rest (when the InlineData values run out)." per: [github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet](http://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet)

(Added as an answer per @AlexAngas suggestion.)

Answer (score -3):

```
[Theory]
[InlineAutoData(null)]
public void FooBar(IBar bar, IFoo foo)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Please provide a little explanation in your answer - code only answers aren't the preference around here

Comment: I agree, this answer needs an explanation as to why it's a good solution, especially as you reversed the parameters, which the questioner has said is undesirable.

Comment: I'm new to this as well, but I think this will explain why: "Uses the InlineData values for the the first method arguments, and then uses AutoData for the rest (when the InlineData values run out)." per: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Cheat-Sheet

Comment: @Eclipse You should add this as an answer

Comment: Won't work anyway since `InlineAutoData` won't accept null, you get an error - `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'InlineAutoDataAttribute.InlineAutoDataAttribute(params object[])' and 'InlineAutoDataAttribute.InlineAutoDataAttribute(AutoDataAttribute, params object[])'`. You could use the `InlineData` attribute instead but you must specify values for all arguments. Worth noting you can use both attributes in the same test but this might reduce the DAMPness of the test.

Comment: Just to make amends for my own dimness: You could make this work by casting the null to the desired type `InlineAutoData((IBar)null)` although it still doesn't alter the fact that you have to switch the order of the parameters.